# Using UART bluetooth module via hciattach

Tags: bluetooth

I have a bluetoothmodule here on my UART and would like to use it via hciattach.
It is a KC21v6.3 Module from kc-Wirefree. As far I found out, it has a CSR-Chip on it. So is tried the following:

```
# hciattach -n -s 115200 /dev/ttyS0 csr
```

That gives me a "Initialization timed out."

If I try the same with the type "any" it works so far that I get a "Device setup complete".

```
# hciconfig
```

gives me a:

```
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: UART
        BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
        DOWN 
        RX bytes:22 acl:0 sco:0 events:0 errors:0
        TX bytes:150 acl:0 sco:0 commands:30 errors:0
```

But after that, when i try to

```
# hciconfig hci0 up
```

I always get an

```
Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)
```

I have no idea what to try any-more. Don't I have to specify the "csr" chip? Or does it have anything to do with the firmware of my KC21 (it understands AT Commands and also has an "AT HciMode" Command) ... I already tried this one before using the "hciattach" command, but nothing changed.

Any help would be appreciated.

kindly regards
Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, today we found out the solution:

The "problem" was, to set the device in "raw" mode, because of the "AT HciMode" command.

```
# hciattach -r /dev/ttyS0 bcsp 115200
```

Maybe it helps somebody.

Comment: Please share more about your project?